# php check if a image file name end is not .jpg, .jpeg, .png or .gif.

Tags: php, regex, mime-types

I tried to save web image to local, I use code here to make a judge, if image file name end is not .jpg, .jpeg, .png or .gif, add them. I use `stripos`, but I meet some trouble when an image url like this. So how to solve? Thanks.

```
$webimage = 'http://pcdn.500px.net/5953805/d0dd841969187f47e8ad9157713949b4b95b3bda/4.jpg?1333782904356';
$pieces = explode("/", $webimage); 
$pathend = end($pieces);
$imageinfo = @getimagesize($webimage);
$imagetype= $imageinfo['mime'];
if($imagetype=='image/jpeg'){
    if(stripos($pathend,'.jpg')==0){
        $newpathend = $pathend.'.jpg'; // if image end is't '.jpg', add '.jpg'
    }else if(stripos($pathend,'.jpeg')==0){
        $newpathend = $pathend.'.jpeg'; // if image end is't '.jpg', add '.jpeg'
    }else{
        $newpathend = $pathend;// if image end is '.jpg' or '.jpeg', do not change
    }
}
if($imagetype=='image/png'){
    if(stripos($pathend,'.png')==0){
        $newpathend = $pathend.'.png'; // if image end is't '.png', add '.png'
    }else{
        $newpathend = $pathend;// if image end is '.png', do not change
    }
}
if($imagetype=='image/gif'){
    if(stripos($pathend,'.gif')==0){
        $newpathend = $pathend.'.gif'; // if image end is't '.gif', add '.gif'
    }else{
        $newpathend = $pathend;// if image end is '.gif', do not change
    }
}
```

Comment: just because a file name ends in .jpg does not make it a jpeg file, better to check the mime type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try like this

```
$type=Array(1 => 'jpg', 2 => 'jpeg', 3 => 'png', 4 => 'gif'); //store all the image extension types in array

$imgname = ""; //get image name here
$ext = explode(".",$imgname); //explode and find value after dot

if(!(in_array($ext[1],$type))) //check image extension not in the array $type
{
    //your code here
}
```

Comment: this is a great way, maybe should add `JPG,JPEG,PNG,GIF` in the array

Comment: You have to change the filename without dots. Otherwise find the length of the array $len=(sizeof($ext)) and replace $ext[1] with $ext[$len-1]

Comment: updated answer with `end($ext)` which will return last index of array and thus extension only

Answer (score 6):

Why not use preg_match?

```
if( preg_match('/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)(?:[\?\#].*)?$/i', $webimage, $matches) ) {
    // matching file extensions are in $matches[1]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This function [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) may help you.

Comment: Does pathinfo properly handle get variables like in the original example?

Answer (score 1):

This works for both jpg as well as jpeg and with uppercase letters.
It also works with filenames like `testing.the.bicycle.jpg`

Give a try on https://regex101.com/r/gI8uS1/1

```
public function is_file_image($filename)
{
   $regex = '/\.(jpe?g|bmp|png|JPE?G|BMP|PNG)(?:[\?\#].*)?$/';

   return preg_match($regex, $filename);
}
```

Comment: hello, What is `(?:[\?\#].*)?` for? I'm a newbie to regex. After some googling got to know that it's a non-capturing group. But didn't understood it. Can you please tell me?

Answer (score 0):

Use **strops**

```
if (strpos($your_text,'.png') !== false) {
        //do something
 } else if (strpos($your_text,'.jpg') !== false) {
        //do something
 } else if (strpos($your_text,'.gif') !== false) {
        //do something
 }
```

Hope it will help!)

Answer (score 0):

refered from **kingjeffrey** answered in this page

```
if( preg_match('/\.(jpg)(?:[\?\#].*)?$/i', $imgname, $matches) ) {
    echo "jpg";
}else if( preg_match('/\.(png)(?:[\?\#].*)?$/i', $imgname, $matches) ) {
    echo "png";
}else if( preg_match('/\.(gif)(?:[\?\#].*)?$/i', $imgname, $matches) ) {
    echo "gif";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$Extension=strrev(substr(strrev($fileName),0,strpos(strrev($fileName),'.')));
if(preg_match('/png|jpg|jpeg|gif/',$Extension))
{ 
    true 
}
else
{ 
    false
}
```